# Interesting question about full rank of random matrix

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a question about rank of a random binary matrix. Assume that I have to make a random binary matrix with its size are k rows and n colmuns (k<=n). Each columns only has 1 or 0 values. Now I want to caculate the probability that the binary matrix is full rank (k). Please help me formula it. Note that 0 and 1 is created with same probability.
This maybe one solution. However, I don't know it is whether correct or not. Let us verify it

[image]
Besides, if the above formula is correct, then  what is probability of G has full rank if n=k?

Comment: This reasoning is valid when the coefficients are viewed as elements of the field $\mathbb{F}_2$, but I do not see why it should hold when the coefficients are viewed as real numbers. In fact, an exhaustive count for $3\times 3$ matrices shows the probability of full rank is $87/256$, which disagrees with the formula.

Comment: The elements of field is in $F_2$ that mean each element of matrix is only 1 or 0. However, for $k=n$ the probability of full rank is 0. Is it valid?

Comment: Don't confuse the symbols with the mathematical object. Although elements of $\mathbb{F}_2$ are commonly denoted "$0$" and "$1$", the operations on them--addition and multiplication--differ from the operations when they represent real numbers.  That's why the results differ depending on which ground field you mean. Regardless--in either case--there is nonzero probability that the matrix will be of full rank when $k=n$. To say otherwise is to assert that no such matrix can be invertible, which obviously is not true (as witnessed by the $n!$ permutation matrices).

Comment: So, what is probability of G has full rank if $n=k$?

Comment: If that is the question you wish to ask, then please edit your post accordingly.

Comment: It is only the sub question. My main question is the formula of probability that G has rank R is whether correct or not?